# is there a way to see a listing of packages ONLY from Debian-experimental?

Tags: debian, grep, apt, regular-expression

I am on Debian testing/Jessie and I have debian-experimental as well as in my /etc/apt/sources.list. So I am looking to list packages in two ways :-

a. List all the packages which are in experimental.

This I was able to achieve by :-

```
$ apt list | grep experimental
```

which gave a listing of all packages which are in experimental. Is there a way though to get a listing of packages who are ONLY in debian-experimental and not in debian-unstable/sid or testing. (I have them in my /etc/apt/sources.list as well.)

If people are wondering, then yes I run a mixed system although majority are from testing.I am sure with grep, awk etc. there would be a way but haven't found it. I looked via search-engines but couldn't come up with an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by listing both sets of packages and determining the difference between the two results:

```
grep -Fxv -f <(apt list | grep unstable | cut -d/ -f1) <(apt list | grep experimental | cut -d/ -f1)
```

This produces “experimental minus unstable”, and can be adapted to calculate any difference by changing `unstable` and/or `experimental`. Strictly speaking it matches more than just the suite; the following variant matches exactly by matching only after the `/` in `apt list`’s output:

```
grep -Fxv -f <(apt list | egrep /.\*unstable | cut -d/ -f1) <(apt list | grep /.\*experimental | cut -d/ -f1)
```

(Otherwise packages with “experimental” in their name appear when they shouldn’t, for example when comparing testing and experimental, `trafficserver-experimental-plugins` is listed even though it’s only present in unstable.)

Furthermore, `apt list` only lists candidate packages by default, so to get the correct results especially when comparing testing and unstable you need to do:

```
grep -Fxv -f <(apt list --all-versions | egrep /.\*unstable | cut -d/ -f1) <(apt list --all-versions | grep /.\*experimental | cut -d/ -f1)
```

Both `cut`s extract the package name from `apt`’s output. The first set of packages (from unstable) is given as a list of patterns for `grep` using the `-f` option. `-F` tells `grep` to consider the patterns as plain text strings rather than regular expressions; `-x` tells it to match each pattern completely; and `-v` tells it to list lines which don’t match the given patterns.
So `grep` takes all the packages in experimental, keeps only those which aren't in the list of packages from unstable, and outputs the result.

The `<()` constructs use process substitution to feed the standard output of the commands contained within the brackets to a pipe which can then be used as input for another command; see [the advanced bash guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html) for details.

Comment: Could you improve that a bit so I can also toss testing in that list, would that be possible ?